# Silverlight - how to send HTML attachment with email?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an online order entry system in silverlight. I need to send an email to the customer with the list of items he has ordered with all the formatting.

In my C# code, I am creating an HTML file with the list of the items and trying to save it before attaching to the email. But when I create the file, I get the exception **"File operation not permitted. Access to path 'C:\test.html' is denied."**

Comment: Out Of Browser Silverlight app or InBrowser?

Comment: Send the data to the server and do it server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight application doesn't have access to client file system, it only has access to my documents when is running out of browser. You should save your file to Isolated Storage. See this [article](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-%28silverlight-quickstart%29).

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 5 you can access to file system under elevated privileges in OOB application. Read more [here](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/silverlight-5-features-local-file.html)